# Install SAS/SATA backplane in Dell PowerVault 220S

Tags: storage, sas, sata, scsi, dell-powervault

Is the backplane of a Dell PowerVault 220S svc tag 3sdpcb1 (14 drive, 80 pin hot swap scsi)
upgradeable to a SAS/SATA backplane & controller card replacement?

The unit already seems to be quite modular, with slide-out replaceable 
scsi controllers/connectors on the back, and slide out redundant power 
supplies.

With everything else so modular, the backplane would seem to be the next
logically upgradeable part of this unit.

Comment: Did you contact Dell Sales to see what they had to say?

Answer (score 1):

These units are rebadged Eurologic arrays and as far as I am aware the answer is no.  There was some parts compatibility with a fibre channel unit, the PV224, but these arrays really predate SAS.  I don't believe that Eurologic (subsequently bought out by Adaptec) ever made a SAS backplane for this chassis, although they did make other SAS/SATA units.